# How to prevent duplicate documents to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

```
my csv file =>
name,surname,age,email,phone
Harry,Potter,18,NULL,NULL
Harry,Potter,NULL,harry.potter@gmail.com,05369564466
Harry,Potter,NULL,harry.potter@gmail.com,NULL
Harry,Potter,NULL,NULL,05369564466
```

When I want to detect and delete duplicate documents with
fingerprint method, it creates a new document for each row.

```
filter {
    fingerprint {
        key => "1234ABCD"
        method => "MD5"
        source => ["name","surname","age","email","phone"]
        target => "[@metadata][generated_id]"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => dots }
    elasticsearch {
        index => "null_problem_fingerprint"
        document_id => "%{[@metadata][generated_id]}"
        action => 'update'
    }
}
```

If I specify only the name and surname fields for the source as in the code blog below
this time it does not read the other rows after reading the first row.

```
filter {
    fingerprint {
        key => "1234ABCD"
        method => "MD5"
        source => ["name","surname"]
        target => "[@metadata][generated_id]"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => dots }
    elasticsearch {
        index => "null_problem_fingerprint"
        document_id => "%{[@metadata][generated_id]}"
        action => 'update'
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: You should review the documentation for the concatenate_sources option to the fingerprint filter and also consider whether you need pipeline.ordered to be true.

Comment: As you said, I `concatenate_sources => "true" ` I also fixed the logstash.yml file as follows, but it still does not work as I want.
pipeline.ordered: true
pipeline.workers : 1